# Is there a way to get bazel to use sandbox directories when sandboxing is not supported?

Tags: docker, go, circleci, bazel

I'm running bazel inside of a docker container. Locally, when I run bazel with no flags I get the following warning:

> WARNING: Sandboxed execution is not supported on your system and thus hermeticity of actions cannot be guaranteed. See http://bazel.build/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#sandboxing for more information. You can turn off this warning via --ignore_unsupported_sandboxing.

And while I lose some guarantees about hermeticity, Bazel still creates all the sandboxing directories before running any of my genrules.

However, in CI, I'm not seeing that warning and instead just get failures when sandboxing is attempted. So I passed `--genrule_strategy=standalone` to stop the crash, but now my genrules are executing right in the workspace, which I definitely don't want.

Is there a way for me to get the behavior I'm seeing locally, where explicit sandboxing calls are being disabled because they would fail but the tmp directory creation with srcs/deps/data being copied over correctly still happens?

Either a flag I could pass to bazel to trigger that behavior, or something I could do to my system to convince bazel that sandboxing is not supported there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What bazel version are you using which crashes when it tries to use sandboxing? I suspect [c2d773ef4c0916a44fd7936f7bbc22ec55102915](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/c2d773ef4c0916a44fd7936f7bbc22ec55102915) will resolve that problem because it makes the detection of whether the sandbox works much more robust, which seems like it would then do what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm using the latest released version, installed with apt-get. 0.4.5 Which looks like it doesn't have the fix you posted. How frequent are bazel releases usually?

Comment: They're typically every month or two, which means the next one is due about now. [#2692](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2692) is the release bug for 0.5.0, and it looks like there's active progress happening on it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible options:

1) To disable sandboxing, `--genrule_strategy=standalone` only applies to `genrule`s. You also need to disable it for other rules, i.e. add `--spawn_strategy=standalone`. You may also need to disable it for specific rule types, e.g. `--strategy GoCompile=standalone`.

2) To use sandboxing, you can run Bazel inside a privileged container, i.e. start its container with the `--privileged` flag. This might be a configuration option in your CI.

Comment: --genrule_strategy & --spawn_strategy should cover everything. But my question is about avoiding calling them.